# Can I Use the Exit(0) function on IOS when i have no Internet Connection and pass Appstore Test

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval, exit-code

My App relay heavily on server data, when i have no connection to my server i cant present any data. so i present to the user a screen explaining him the no connection situation and give him a button to exit the application
my question is: will it pass Appstore tests? i never tried it before and i know they dont like apps to use exit(0), i was also was suggested to put a screen with no buttons and block the user from going back to other app screens and put a message on this screen and make the user to click on the home button in order not to use exit(0)
is that allowed?

Comment: Rather force an exit, in my opinion you would be better to revert to a mode where you attempt to re-connect to the internet at some predefined rate.  Losing a wireless connection is something that will happen at some point and you need to recover/reconnect in a predictable/seamless manner in order to provide the best user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you must not call `exit`. Your app will be rejected. This has been repeatedly discouraged by Apple and is known to cause serious bugs with iOS multitask switching. You should simply leave the user to use the home button themselves.

Answer (score 3):

> Do not call the exit function. Applications calling exit will appear to the user to have crashed, rather than performing a graceful termination and animating back to the Home screen.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1561/_index.html

Comment: Thanks!lupatus ill look for another way